# recursive to find number of nested list and element value if depth reaches 0

Tags: python, recursion

I have a nested list and I want to return the number of nested list (or the depth) and the element value if the depth reaches `0`. For example, with below nested list, the value I want to return is `(13, 37)`. But my code returns `36` only.

```
nested = [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[13]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]

def search(a, depth=0):
    count = 0
    for e in a:
        if isinstance(e, list):
            count = count + 1 + search(e)
    return count
    
search(nested)
```

How should correct my code to make it return (13, 37) as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the right answer for a single value wrapped in a single set of lists. Not sure why you are iterating over the elements of the list. Are there potentially multiple nested sub lists/values?

```
nested = [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[13]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
def search(a, depth=0):
  if type(a) is list:
     return search(a[0], depth + 1)
  else:
    return a, depth
    
print(search(nested))
```

Comment: Your code works well. The reason I iterated over elements of the list is that I am not familiar with recursion, so I have mixed up with "for" loop unexpectedly. Could you explain the "a[0]" part? Does it represent the element value of the lowest "depth"?

Comment: a[0] returns the first element in the list. Because all the lists only have 1 item in them (either the value or another list), calling a[0] recursively is how you drill down

Answer (score 1):

You're not counting the outermost list. To correct this, pull the list check outside of the loop. To return the inner value, retrieve it when the list element is not a list anymore:

```py
def search(a):
    count = 0
    if isinstance(a, list):
        count += 1
        for e in a:
            inner_value, count_inc = search(e) 
            count += count_inc
    else:
        inner_value = a
    return inner_value, count
```

Comment: This does not return the desired answer (13,37).  Also depth is the same as count.  See Ruswick's answer.

Comment: I edited the answer to return the inner value in addition to the depth.

Comment: The whole point of recursion is to avoid the for loop.  Again see Ruswick's answer.

Comment: You are confusing two different iterations here. The recursion is for the depth, but I was assuming there might be several elements in the lists. The above function counts all the lists on all levels.

Answer (score 1):

A good recursive function has a base case and a recursive case.  Ruswick's (good) answer can be modified to meet these criteria:

```
def search(a, depth=0):
    if type(a) is int: #base case
        return a, depth
    return search(a[0], depth + 1) #recusive case

print(search(nested))
#(13, 37)
```

Comment: Thanks for good explanation. It helps me understand the base case

Comment: This is not an improvement. Ruswick's answer already has the base case covered by the `else` statement. Your function will fail if the list contains non-integers.

Comment: It is not supposed to be an improvement. I upvoted Ruswick’s answer. It is supposed to follow the formal format of a recursive function, where the base case is defined first and the recursive case follows. It helped OP understand it better by adhering to the textbook format. With regard to the integer issue, the code can easily be changed to type(a) is not list, if op plans to include non-integer items.

Comment: Fair enough. Upvoted for educational effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function to handle inputs with more than one non-list element:

```
def search(d, c = 0):
   for i in d:
      if not isinstance(i, list):
         yield (i, c)
      else:
         yield from search(i, c+1)


nested = [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[13]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
print(list(search(nested)))
```

Output:

```
[(13, 36)]
```